# Can't install a UI toolkite for expo

Tags: javascript, user-interface, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, expo

I am using expo to build apps in react-native. for navigation and design I wanted to use a UI toolkite instead of styling everything myself.

the problem is I tired all UI toolkites but none of them was installed. it give the following error in the terminal:

[image]
I tired installing the remote-ls through **C:\Users\YOUNES\RNProject>npm-remote-ls sha@1.2.4** and installed git for windows7 yet nothing seem to work it is still giving me the same errors!!

help please!

Comment: Please try to install git => https://git-scm.com/

Comment: already installed git but still the error is occuring -same error-